# Remplazar valores según la restricción de dos variables

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de automatizar algunos cambios que quiero hacer en un archivo txt con el siguiente formato.

```
        Value    Id
      1 1    Patch
      2 1    stratum 
      3 34.1 x
      4 0.8  y
      5 1    stratum 
      6 36.3 x
      7 1.1  y
      8 2    Patch
      9 1    stratum 
      10 35.2    x
      11 0.8 y
      12 3   Patch
      13 1   stratum 
      14 36.7    x
      15 0.7 y
      16 1   stratum 
      17 35.9    x
      18 0.5 y
      19 4   Patch
      20 1   stratum 
      21 32.1 x
      22 0.9 y
```

Estoy tratando de cambiar el valor del Stratum con los valores de una lista (New_Stratum), para cada Patch. Pero también hay Patch con 2 Stratum que deberían tener el mismo valor.

```
     Patch = [1,2,3,4]

     New_Stratum=[0.9,0.8,0.6,0.5]
```

El resultado esperado sería:

```
        Value    Id
      1 1    Patch
      2 0.9  stratum 
      3 34.1 x
      4 0.8  y
      5 0.9  stratum 
      6 36.3 x
      7 1.1  y
      8 2    Patch
      9 0.8  stratum 
      10 35.2    x
      11 0.8 y
      12 3   Patch
      13 0.6 stratum 
      14 36.7    x
      15 0.7 y
      16 0.6 stratum 
      17 35.9    x
      18 0.5 y
      19 4   Patch
      20 0.5 stratum 
      21 32.1 x
      22 0.9 y
```

Como se puede ver, sería modificar las lineas:

-Patch 1: (lineas 2 y 5) de 1 a 0.9 #ya que tiene dos capas, debe repetir el valor

-Patch 2: (linea 9) de 1 a 0.8

-Patch 3: (lineas 13 y 16) de 1 a 0.6 #ya que tiene dos capas, debe repetir el valor

-Patch 4: (linea 20) de 1 a 0.5

No sé si puedes guiarme en cómo formular el código.

Creo que es la mejor idea que he tenido para abordarlo, pero no creo que sea del todo correcto...

```
        file = 'C:/delete/file.txt'
        Patch = [1,2,3,4]
        New_Stratum = [0.9,0.8,0.6,0.5]
        result = ""
        for i,j in zip(Patch,New_Stratum):
            with open(file) as f:
                for line in f.readlines():            
                    while line.startswith(i):
                        if line[1] == 'Stratum':
                            line[0] == str(j)
                        result += line
                f = open(file, 'w')
                f.write(result)
                f.close()
```

Muchas gracias si podeis ayudarme!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido a Stack overflow!

Si la lectura del archivo es en forma linear podrias guardar una variable con el patch actual:

```
current_patch = None
```

Luego tienes que ir linea por linea y aquí tienes tres escenarios:

**a. tienes un `Patch`**: En este caso guardas el valor del patch en el current patch y sigues:

```
m = re.split(r"\s+", line)
current_patch = m[1]
```

**b. tienes un `stratum`**: En este caso buscas el `current_patch` y lo reemplazas por el valor que deseas:

```
m = re.split(r"\s+", line)
m[1] = statum_values[int(current_patch)]
```

**c. tienes otro valor**: En este caso sigues el ciclo normal (yo igual lo divido en una lista para formatearlo después:

```
m = re.split(r"\s+", line)
```

Al final de la iteración formateamos la lista a un texto y lo guardamos en el archivo:

```
format_line = '{number:2} {value:<4} {type}'.format(number=m[0], value=m[1], type=m[2])
```

Aquí pongo el código completo:

```
import re

filename = 'file.txt'

Patch = [1,2,3,4]
New_Stratum=[0.9,0.8,0.6,0.5]

statum_values = dict(zip(Patch, New_Stratum))

result = ""

with open(filename) as f:
    current_patch = None
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'Patch' in line:
            m = re.split(r"\s+", line)
            # result
            # ['1', '1', 'Patch', '']
            current_patch = m[1]
        elif 'stratum' in line:
            m = re.split(r"\s+", line)
            # ['2', '1', 'stratum', '']
            # reemplazamos aqui
            m[1] = statum_values[int(current_patch)]
        else:
            # procesamos la linea tal cual
            m = re.split(r"\s+", line)

        # formateatmos y fuardamos
        format_line = '{number:2} {value:<4} {type}\n'.format(number=m[0], value=m[1], type=m[2])
        result += format_line

with open('2'+filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda! estoy probandolo y me sale el siguiente error: (  m[1] = statum_values[int(current_patch)]

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Patch'. 

No se muy bien porque.

Comment: Ya he visto mi error, es que el valor inicial de cada linea (1,2,3,4,5...) no aparece en mi fichero. solo he modificado los valores m[1] por m[0] y la linea:
        format_line = '{value:<4} {type}\n'.format(value=m[0], type=m[1]). Muchas gracias de verdad! llevaba bastante tiempo luchando con este código y tu explicación me ha servido para entender el procedimiento. Un saludo!